# SQL- Between.. and... combined with YEAR()

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query which gives me an error about  incorrect syntax!

```
SELECT  tel_no 
FROM  donors AS  dnr 
LEFT JOIN  donations AS  dn ON  dnr.id =  dn.donor_id
LEFT JOIN  donation_methods AS  dm ON  dn.donation_method_id =  dm.id
WHERE  NOW() >= DATE_ADD(dn.created, INTERVAL dm.recovery_time DAY)
AND dnr.gender = 'female'
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dnr.dob) - YEAR() BETWEEN 40 AND 54 //syntax error here
AND dnr.blood_group_id = 2
```

It is giving me this error :

`check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') BETWEEN 40 AND 54 AND dnr.blood_group_id = 2`

Where is the incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`YEAR()` requires a date/dateime argument. All you need is

```
AND YEAR(dnr.dob) - YEAR(CURDATE()) BETWEEN 40 AND 54
```

Note that your arguments are reversed, unless you' actually dealign with future dates of birth. You'll be doing

```
AND (1973 - 2014) BETWEEN 40 AND 54  which becomes -41 BETWEEN 40 AND 54
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! perfect, yes I must have been living on the moon to have reversed the args! once again, thanks

Comment: The method is actually CURDATE().. for anyone who might run into trouble with this..